# Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown.'

Tags: c#

Why this? This is my code.
This is my "Kwadrat" class

```
public class Kwadrat : FormView
{
    public int X {get;set;}
    public int Y {get;set;}
    public Kwadrat Parent { get; set; }

    public void pozycja()
    {

        X = Parent.X;
        Y = Parent.Y;
    }

}
```

In this line visual Studio show me a error

```
Kwadrat k1 = new Kwadrat();
```

This is FormView.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ObjectMoving
{
public partial class FormView : Form
{
    enum Position
    {
        Left, Right, Up, Down
    };
    private int NUMBER_OF_SQUARES=20;
    private int SQUARE_SIZE=15;
    Point _start = new Point(30,30);
    private Position _objPosition;
    Kwadrat k1 = new Kwadrat();
    Kwadrat k2 = new Kwadrat();
    private Kwadrat k3 = new Kwadrat();
    List<Rectangle> Snake = new List<Rectangle>();
    Losowanie l1=new Losowanie();

    public FormView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _objPosition = Position.Down;

        k1.X = 30;
        k1.Y = 60;

        k2.Parent = k1;
        k2.X = 30;
        k2.Y = 45;

        k3.Parent = k2;
        k3.X = 30;
        k3.Y = 30;
        l1.losowa();



    }

    private void FormView_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= NUMBER_OF_SQUARES; i++)
        {
            //rysowanie lini horyzontalnych
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Red),
                _start.X,
                _start.Y + SQUARE_SIZE * i,
                _start.X + SQUARE_SIZE * NUMBER_OF_SQUARES,
                _start.Y + SQUARE_SIZE * i);

            //Rysowanie lini wertykalnych
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Brown),
                _start.X + SQUARE_SIZE * i,
                _start.Y,
                _start.X + SQUARE_SIZE * i,
                _start.Y + SQUARE_SIZE * NUMBER_OF_SQUARES);
        }


        e.Graphics.FillRectangle((Brushes.Aqua), k1.X, k1.Y, SQUARE_SIZE,        SQUARE_SIZE);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle((Brushes.Aqua), k2.X, k2.Y, SQUARE_SIZE, SQUARE_SIZE);

        e.Graphics.FillRectangle((Brushes.Aqua), k3.X, k3.Y, SQUARE_SIZE, SQUARE_SIZE);

        e.Graphics.FillRectangle((Brushes.Red),l1.RandomNumber, l1.RandomNumber2, SQUARE_SIZE, SQUARE_SIZE);

        //foreach (Rectangle Object in Snake)
        //{
        //    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Aqua), k3.X, k3.Y, SQUARE_SIZE, SQUARE_SIZE);
        //}




    }


    //odswiezanie
    public void tmrMoving_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //kolizja();
        k3.pozycja();

        k2.pozycja();




        if (_objPosition == Position.Right)
        {



            k1.X += 15;



        }
        else if (_objPosition == Position.Left)
        {

            k1.X -= 15;
        }
        else if (_objPosition == Position.Up)
        {

            k1.Y -= 15;
        }

        else if (_objPosition == Position.Down)
        {

            k1.Y += 15;
        }
        if (k1.X < 29)
        {
            tmrMoving.Enabled = false;
            tmrMoving.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show("Wyjechales poza plansze");
            Application.Exit();

        }
        else if (k1.X > 315)
        {
            tmrMoving.Enabled = false;
            tmrMoving.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show("Wyjechales poza plansze");
            Application.Exit();

        }
        else if(k1.Y<29)
        {
            tmrMoving.Enabled = false;
            tmrMoving.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show("Wyjechales poza plansze");
            Application.Exit();

        }
        else if (k1.Y > 315)
        {
            tmrMoving.Enabled = false;
            tmrMoving.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show("Wyjechales poza plansze");
            Application.Exit();

        }

        Invalidate();
    }
    //ruch strzalkami
    private void FormView_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {
           // s1.Sprawdzenie();           

            _objPosition = Position.Left;

        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {
            _objPosition = Position.Right;



        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        {
            _objPosition = Position.Up;
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        {
            _objPosition = Position.Down;
        }
    }

    //public void kolizja()
    //{

    //    if (k1.X == l1.RandomNumber && k1.Y == l1.RandomNumber2)
    //    {
    //        l1.losowa();

    //        Snake.Add(new Rectangle(k3.X, k3.Y, 15, 15));

    //    }
    //}







}
```

}

Comment: It does not give me error, unless you are doing something else in its constructor.

Comment: So i will show you all my code

Comment: Provide an [mcve]. The code you show by itself works. check [ask] again as well...

Comment: "So i will show you all my code" - and the stacktrace please!

Comment: Unrelated : `X = Parent.X;` if Parent is null, this will throw a NullReferenceException.

Comment: Unrelated, too: Chosing english names makes your code more readable to users in an international environment such as SO.

Comment: Ok, i will keep this advice ;D

Answer (score 7):

The problem you have here is a flavour of "circular reference".

Your `Kwadrat` class is based on `FormView`, which means that whenever you create a new instance of `Kwadrat`, for example, the line you've called out where `k1` is constructed, this means that the following happens:

1. We're creating a new instance of `Kwadrat`, so lets call its constructor
2. It inherits from `FormView`, so lets call its constructor and set its member variables, etc,..
3. We're in `FormView`, it needs an instance of `Kwadrat`, called K1, lets create that

Right now we loop back to "1" and then repeat forever, which is why you're receiving the `StackOverflowException` that you are. In this instance, the fact that the class we're looking at contains a property called `Parent` that is typed as itself is a "red herring" as it's not the cause of the error, though if you ever ended up with an instance of `Kwadrat` where `Parent` was set to self (e.g.`instance.Parent = instance;`) you'd potentially see the same error if an attempt was made to traverse the hierarchy of parents for that instance.

Comment: Solution: Kwadrat should not be based on FormView.

Comment: Ok. Thank you a lot for this. I was surprised because when i wrote it yesterday it worked